# VBA Connection from Excel 2010 to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, vba, database-connection, excel-2010

i'm pretty new to SQL and VBA, so please forgive any audacity the code below may contain. I am working with code written in Excel's VBA. Eventually, the data from the user form in excel will be entered into a SQL database I have created using SQL Server 2008. Right now, I am just trying to open the connection to the SQL database and enter hard coded values into the db. Unfortunately, this has been much more of a challenge than I expected. I have tried playing around with the connection string a few different ways but have had no luck. When the form runs, I get no errors and I can see the data was added into the appropriate excel worksheet (but no changes in the SQL DB). I can see the db on SQL Server Management Studio and add rows from there, but I am unable to add a row to the db via this code. The db is protected solely by windows authentication. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub ConnectSqlServer()
'********SPC DATABASE CONNECTION**********************
'write slurry information to database
'spc_date, mix_type, slurry_lot_num, mixer_num, shift, oper

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String

'Create connection string
sConnString = "Provider=sqloledb; Server=SERV; Database=db; Trusted_Connection=True;"

'Create the Connection and Recordset objects
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

'Open connection and execute
conn.Open sConnString
Set rs = conn.Execute("INSERT INTO TBL (col1, col2) VALUES ('val', 'val');")

'Clean up
If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?  Note that an `insert` will not return a recordset.

Comment: I do not get any error messages, but when I go to SQL Server Managment Studio and view the table I can see that the values I tried to add to the table were not added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting data, you don't need a recordset object, since an `INSERT` statement doesn't return a recordset. Instead, try using a command object instead. The command object gives you more control over how your SQL statement is passed to the server, and it also gives you a way to test whether any records were inserted.

I'd also recommend setting `Option Explicit` at the top of each module, since it will stop you from making mistakes with variables (for instance, you have both `conn` and `oConn` in your code, which I don't think you intended.

Here are my edits to your code. It's untested, but I think I've got it right. If it runs without any errors, and `recordsAffected` returns 1, but there's still nothing on the server, then we'll have to do some more digging.

```
Sub ConnectSqlServer()
'********SPC DATABASE CONNECTION**********************
'write slurry information to database
'spc_date, mix_type, slurry_lot_num, mixer_num, shift, oper

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim sConnString As String
Dim recordsAffected as Long

'Create connection string
sConnString = "Provider=sqloledb; Server=SERV; Database=db; Trusted_Connection=True;"

'Open connection and execute
conn.Open sConnString
With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = conn
  .CommandType = adCmdText
  .CommandText = "INSERT INTO TBL (col1, col2) VALUES ('val', 'val');"
  .Execute recordsAffected 'Includes a return parameter to capture the number of records affected
End With

Debug.Print recordsAffected 'Check whether any records were inserted

'Clean up
If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
Set cmd = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Jeff. I tried using this instead of my original code and the same thing happened - I did not get any errors but no rows were added to the database. My code is all in Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications - do you know where recordsAffected would be printed out? (sorry for the slow response - the site was under maintenance for a little)

Comment: In the Visual Basic Editor, press Ctrl+G to open the Immediate Window. That's where Debug.Print spits out its results. You'll probably have to run it again to see anything. Let me know what shows up.

Comment: Gotcha..thanks again. Ran it again and nothing was printed out in the immediate window

Comment: Are you positive the code is actually being run? Because I would very much have expected your original code to return an error. Try this: place your cursor somewhere early in the code, maybe on `conn.Open sConnString`, and press F9 to create a breakpoint, then run things again. Your code should pause execution and be highlighted in yellow; you can then run through the procedure step by step by pressing F8. This may show you what's going wrong, but I'm wondering if the breakpoint will even be hit at all.

Comment: Progress! At first you were correct, the breakpoint wasn't reached. I took out the Sub and End Sub and put in with the code that adds the data to the excel worksheet. Once I did this, it hit the breakpoint. After hitting F8 it was able to run my sConnString="...." line, but at the conn.Open sConnString I am getting an "invalid connection string attribute" error

Comment: Yes, I expect this is the error you would have been receiving in the first place. For help building your connection string, try the following link: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: For `sqloledb`, I think you want 'Data Source' and 'Initial Catalog', not 'Server' and 'Database' in the connection string.

Comment: I changed "Trusted_Connection=True;" to "Integrated Security=SSPI;" and it got rid of the error and added the row. Thank you SO much for your help!